# Parsing and displaying XML with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I need(want) to parse Nessus output(XML) with a ruby script and eventually have it output to CSV and HTML files. I am brand new to Ruby so would just be happy with some output to the terminal for now while I learn. Below are samples of the Nessus output and the script I have built so far. The script doesn't return any errors as is but also does not return any of the data I need. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
</NessusClientData_v2>
</Report>
</ReportHost> 
<ReportItem port="0" svc_name="general" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="12053" pluginName="Host Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) Resolution" pluginFamily="General">
<description>Nessus was able to resolve the FQDN of the remote host.</description>
<fname>fqdn.nasl</fname>
<plugin_modification_date>2012/09/28</plugin_modification_date>
<plugin_name>Host Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) Resolution</plugin_name>
<plugin_publication_date>2004/02/11</plugin_publication_date>
<plugin_type>remote</plugin_type>
<risk_factor>None</risk_factor>
<script_version>$Revision: 1.12 $</script_version>
<solution>n/a</solution>
<synopsis>It was possible to resolve the name of the remote host.</synopsis>
<plugin_output>
12.233.108.201 resolves as preprod.boardvantage.net.
</plugin_output>
</ReportItem>
<ReportItem port="443" svc_name="https?" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11219" pluginName="Nessus SYN scanner" pluginFamily="Port scanners">
<description>This plugin is a SYN &apos;half-open&apos; port scanner.
It shall be reasonably quick even against a firewalled target.

Note that SYN scanners are less intrusive than TCP (full connect) scanners against broken services, but they might kill lame misconfigured firewalls. They might also leave unclosed connections on the remote target, if the network is loaded.</description>
<fname>nessus_syn_scanner.nbin</fname>
<plugin_modification_date>2011/04/05</plugin_modification_date>
<plugin_name>Nessus SYN scanner</plugin_name>
<plugin_type>remote</plugin_type>
<risk_factor>None</risk_factor>
<script_version>$Revision: 1.14 $</script_version>
<solution>Protect your target with an IP filter.</solution>
<synopsis>It is possible to determine which TCP ports are open.</synopsis>
<plugin_output>Port 443/tcp was found to be open</plugin_output>
</ReportItem>
</ReportHost>
</Report>
</NessusClientData_v2>
```

NessusParse.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'nokogiri'

Nessus_to_parse = gets

doc = Nokogiri::XML(Nessus_to_parse)
doc.xpath('//ReportItem').each do |i|
  puts "Host = " + i.at_xpath('name').content
  puts "Name = " + i.at_xpath('plugin_name').content
  puts "Severity = " + i.at_xpath('risk_factor').content
end
```